# Xamarin and Web API

Tags: asp.net, xamarin.forms

I have been struggling with this now for couple of days. I have a Xamarin App running on Emulator, which is attempting to connect to Web API running on my local machine. I tried connecting via the IP 10.0.2.2, which I believe is the IP for connecting to local pc from emulator (please correct me if am wrong).

The API runs on IIS Express. Could someone guide me ?

Comment: use the actual IP of the server.  Connectivity between the emulator (presumably you mean Android) and the PC is an Android networking issue, it has nothing to do with Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the web service is accessible from your app browser is a good starting point.

It is really simple to do this using SharpProxy. The [link](https://www.barelycompetent.co.za/debugging-your-rest-service-from-your-emulator-device-using-sharpproxy/) of the article: